# Auto layout Constraints on NSView Only Obeyed After Hitting Edge

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout, nstableview, nsview

[image: Shown on 10.10, but reproduced on 10.7 and above]

(Shown on 10.10, but reproduced on 10.7 and above)

I've got a Mac menu bar application that starts by loading an NSOutlineView and populating a few view-based cells. Upon selecting the cell the NSOutlineView is hidden, and a new NSTableView (TicketViewController) is presented. The custom NSTableViewCell (CommentComposeCellView) contains a NSTextView and a custom NSView (CommentComposeFooterView) that contains an NSImageView and an NSButton. The NSTableViewCell and custom NSView both have Autolayout constraints so that they should match the size of the window they're contained in. However, when resizing the window the custom NSView does not resize until the window's edge touches the custom NSView.

```
-(void)outlineViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
if ([self.outlineView selectedRow] != -1) {
    id clickedItem = [self.outlineView itemAtRow:[self.outlineView selectedRow]];
if ([clickedItem isKindOfClass:[Request class]]){
        [self.ticketViewController displayRequest:clickedItem];
        [self.scrollView setHidden:YES];

        NSView *contentView = [self.window contentView];
        [[self.ticketViewController view] setFrame:[contentView bounds]];
        [[self.ticketViewController view] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [contentView addSubview:[self.ticketViewController view]];
        NSView *ticketView = [self.ticketViewController view];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(ticketView);
        [contentView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[ticketView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:views]];

        [contentView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[ticketView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:views]];
}
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Are there constraints to relate Comment Compose Footer View to its superview (Comment Compose Cell View)? It's not just the "Add reply" button that's failing to track, it's the view it's in, as indicated by the background. Also, IB is indicating a constraints error (arrow in red circle). You need to address that.

Comment: Hey Ken, there is a trailing and leading space to superview constraint on Comment Compose Footer View. Also, the layout issue has been taken care of. I was able to work around the issue by programmatically resizing the table column these cells live in, but it seems strange I can't take care of it in auto layout.

Comment: Unrelated to your original issue:  
as long as your views are in Auto Layout mode there is no point in setting their frames directly: `[[self.ticketViewController view] setFrame:[contentView bounds]];` The frame values you set are going to be overwritten during the view layout pass. `-setFrame:` can still be useful only in cases where you opt-out of auto layout mode for a subtree and layout subviews manually.

Comment: In other words, adding a view to a container with an appropriate constraints is just enough.

Comment: I hope your workaround works, but without understanding the reason for the problem how can you be confident that it will?

Comment: Konstantin : Thanks. Ken: In looking at the view hierarchy it looks like the CommentComposeFooterView is using the table column as its' super view. This makes sense to me, but I'm still not understanding why then the table column resizes only after the window has been resized and the edge hits.

Comment: A table column isn't a view so it can't be anything's superview. A table cell view is contained in the table row view, which is contained in the table view. The width of the column(s) should dictate the position of the cell view within the row view. That leads to another thought: how have you configured the table view with respect to column autoresizing as the table view changes width? Are you sure the column initially fills the width of the table view? How is the scroll view containing table view configured to resize with with the window? (Use "@Ken" in replies so I get notified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added

```
[tableColumn setWidth:self.view.superview.frame.size.width]
```

to

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row
```